# Emojis in VSCode

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code, flutter

Im trying to edit the following array of emojis in dart, I tried emoji extensions in VSCode but none are working for this line of code.

const _emojis = ['','','','',''];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dart Strings appear to be [UTF-16 sequences](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-core/String-class.html). So find the UTF sequences for those emoji and use them as described in that link.

The simplest naïve case, that of Unicode code points, would be:

```
const _emojis = ['\u{1f605}','\u{1f606}','\u{1f607}','\u{1f608}','\u{1f609}'];

for (var i = 0;i<_emojis.length;i++) {
   print("Position $i : ${_emojis[i]} ");
}
```

There are helpers for this as well:

> For a character outside the Basic Multilingual Plane (plane 0) that is
>   composed of a surrogate pair, runes combines the pair and returns a
>   single integer

In fact, you are recommended to *not* use raw lists for this as it can [lead to problems down the road](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21521729/1531971). The Language Tour specifically calls this out:

> Note: Be careful when manipulating runes using list operations. This
>   approach can easily break down, depending on the particular language,
>   character set, and operation.

Also, see the [Dart String tutorial](https://www.dartlang.org/samples#strings) and the [Language Tour](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour) (which actually shows a solution to this exact question).

Comment: I found the code but it doesnt work in VS Code.  U+1F636

Comment: You are encouraged to edit your question and show your [mcve] and explain the results you get. One immediate guess is that your _output_ is expecting a specific character set, or the glyphs are missing in the font. But we don't know until you show us.

Comment: The results I get are the emoji doesnt show up when I enter the UTF code "U+1F636"

Comment: UTF code works once the code runs in the emulator, I still dont know how the emojies are showing up whereever I paste them, even in notepad :) .   This code works:      const _emojis = ['\u{1f605}','\u{1f606}','\u{1f607}','\u{1f608}','\u{1f609}'];

Comment: How an editor handles what an operating system does when pasting from the clipboard isn't a great place to start, as there are way too many moving parts there. That being said, some of this stuff can be a bit opaque, but it is understandable. I suggest starting here: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/